# How do I find all the WebApplicationInitializers in my war files

Tags: spring, jetty

I'm getting the following message when Jetty launches my webapp:

```
main: 3 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
```

How do I get Jetty to tell my the classpaths of all the WebApplicationInitializers that it found?

Comment: Jetty is not involved in that step.  Spring is the one looking for WebApplicationInitializers (in the past it did its own bytecode scanning for them, not sure what version of Spring you are using and what its doing now)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt SpringMVC 4.3.4